# getUserId does not exist in User.Identity in rc1.final

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net 5 and entity framework 7 to create a web application, and I am having some issues with getting `User.Identity` to work. In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getuserid(v=vs.108).aspx), it says it lies in the namespace `User.Identity.Core`. When I install this via nuget, it finds the method. However, I get conflicts with `UserManager`, as it says it exists in both `User.Identity.Core` and `User.Identity.EntityFramework`. If i uninstall `User.Identity.EntityFramework`, I am not allowed to inherit from `IdentityUser` in my User-model. I need the `GetUserId` in order to get the current logged inn user... I've also tried to use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

But there seems to be a similar problem, where it says `Current` does not exist in `HttpContext`.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

**Update with project.json:**

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-FrkKantine-1a8100b9-6fce-44b4-ac9d-6038ecf705f6",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Razor": "4.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnx50": {}
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The methods you are referring to are about .NET Framework 4.x and the old Identity. All the types in `System.Web.*` basically refer to the old ASP.NET which was tightly coupled to IIS. The `HttpContext` abstract class in .NET Core is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` for example. Some very basic official documentation on asp.net core can be found here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/. But it's **very incomplete**, but a good start for some of the basics

Comment: Can you post your project.json, at least the dependencies/framework bits?

Comment: What is the solution for this question for ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM/EnitityFramework 1.0 Core?

Answer (score 7):

Since ASP.NET Core 1.0 (former ASP.NET 5) is still in development, things change often.

Please check out the GitHub [Announcements tracker](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) for API changes the ASP.NET Core 1.0 releases (don't post issues there though, it's purely for the ASP.NET Core team to post announcements).

One of [these announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/140) is about the moving of `GetUsername`, `GetUserId` and `IsSignedIn` extension methods.

> The claims that these extension methods refer to are configurable via
>   IdentityOptions which was not currently being respected by the
>   extensions methods which always referred to the build in
>   ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier/Name.
>
> These methods have been moved to address this:  Before => After
>
> ```
> User.GetUserId => UserManager.GetUserId(User)
> User.GetUserName => UserManager.GetUserName(User)
> User.IsSignedIn => SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)
> ```

**edit:**
I just noticed it's for RC2, so likely not yet apply to you unless you use nightly builds feed.

Your issue may come from choosing the wrong package names, as they have been renamed a half dozen of times in the past

`EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` should be the ones for you. (with RC2 they got another rename to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` and all versions reset to 1.0)

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried looking through the announcements, but I missed that one. Sorry for (probably) stupid questions, but...If GetUserId takes in a User, how do I find the User which is logged in? Or, how do I get the User object to pass to GetUserId?

Comment: The logged in user still inside the `HttpContext`. if you're inside a controller (that derives from `Controller` type, otherwise same as service applies for POCO Controllers), you can access it via `HttpContext` (or just `Context`, it has been renamed a few times). If you need it in a service, you have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your service and access it via it's `HttpContext` property

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I actually have the methods in UserManager, even though I think I am using RC1. I still can't get it to work to get the Id for the user, but I think I'll just stop trying and instead use the Name, and require a unique username for the users...

Comment: @JulieRøsok: Add your projects.json to the question, may be a mix of old and new packages. They changed quite often

Comment: Done :) But it seems to work quite well with Name as well... I was planning on using the email as login/username anyways, so I think it will be fine. But please feel free to look at the json and see if there is anything wrong with the packages!

Comment: Bummer.. You can't injection UserManager into ApplicationDbContext because that creates a circular dependency. GetUserId() was more useful for auditing purposes than username.

Comment: @AlexDresko: DbContext shouldn't ever be aware of UserManager. Whatever you tried, it's plain wrong and you should reconsider your design

Comment: @Tseng I get what you're saying, believe me. But how else would you do something like this? https://gist.github.com/alexdresko/d25e691708c8f919a524422f86be1466

Essentially, I'm overriding SaveChanges so I can set the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy values automatically for all of my entities. Seemed like the easiest thing to do and has worked flawlessly in several projects for a very long time.  In EF6, I was able to `GetUserId`, but EF Core requires that I only store the user name which isn't necessarily unique.

Comment: @AlexDresko: https://gist.github.com/alexdresko/d25e691708c8f919a524422f86be1466#file-savechangesauditing-cs-L20 Since you have an HttpContext there, you can also resolve it via `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()` there to get it. Since you don't inject it via constructor (or resolve it in the constructor) there is no circular dependency as at the time of calling `SaveChanges()` your context has already been instantiated.

Comment: @AlexDresko: ... It still feels a bit 'dirty', because it's a bad practice call the IoC container in code like this, making it hard to unit test. So the cleaner way would be to extract this into an `IUserManagerFactory` interface and `UserManagerFactory` class, inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` there and have a method `GetUserManager` to return the `UserManager` service. The factory now does the same (ask the container for a service), but that's okay, because it's a factory. And for unit tests you can mock your factory and this way also test your `ModifyBaseEntity` method for correct behavior

Comment: @Tseng That still creates a circular dependency. Plus, I'm not doing anything with the IoC container in that gist. DI is injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor` which could definitely be replaced with something a little less "webby", but that's not the point. The point in my original comment was the injecting `UserManager` into `ApplicationDbContext` isn't possible because it creates a circular dependency.

Comment: @AlexDresko: But only if you do it in the constructor. The above effectively deffer the resolution of `UserManager` until `SaveChanges()` is called and at this point the `ApplicationDbcontext` has already been created and any call to `.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()` returns the already initialized version. `DbContext` is by **default** registered as scope (=singleton for the duration the request). If you still receive an error, post a question with the code, exact error message and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Try This :

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

and then :

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

**Solution 2 :**

usually you should make sure if the user Authenticated and then get the user info / id :

```
if (model != null)
    {
        model.IsUserAuthenticated = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (model.IsUserAuthenticated)
        {
            model.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As I tried to explain in the question, If I am just using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, it can't find the method GetUserId. There seems to be some changes in the latest version, and GetUserId is no longer a part of AspNet.Identity, but it is in AspNet.Identity.Core, which is a different dll and causes conflicts if I try to install it...The other code you posted works for getting the Name, but I need to get the Id for queries (as Name might not be unique)

Comment: In asp.net core RC2 the GetUserId() isn't there by default, also instead of checking if the user is authenticated couldn't you just decorate the action or controller with [Authorize]?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Core <= RC1 Update 1, you still can use the GetUserId() extension.

References required:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;
```

Usage:
`var id = User.GetUserId();` (and not `User.Identity.GetUserId()`)

Another different thing you mention is about `HttpContext.Current` being null, from which I assume you are trying to access the user from a class library or outside the MVC's scope.

If you need to access the HttpContext from a class library you can't just access it like a static property.
**It is required to be injected in that class**.

Just do the following:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public MyRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Then you can use it through all the methods in the class like this:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.GetUserId();
```